# Smart gwt window position

Tags: window, smartgwt

How do I make a window popup in a specific location on the page? I don't see a straightforward way of doing this, so I'm always using window.centerInPage()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the underlying setRect() method of Canvas: [Canvas.setRect(int left, int top, int width, int height)](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html#setRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

```
window.setRect(250, 100, 500 500);
```

Remember to redraw as needed.

Or, if you're using the GWT Window, you can achieve that by using the [Window.open(String url, String target, String features)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#open%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method, as specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3awindow.open).

```
Window.open(URL, "newWindow", "left=250,top=100,width=500,height=500");
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is the best way, but works:

```
int browserInnerWidth = com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.getClientWidth();
myWindow.show();
myWindow.setLeft(browserInnerWidth - windowWidth);
```